# how do i set default value in column annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, pojo

I am new in java. i created a entity class. where i wanted a default value for a field. i tried `@Column(name = "ProjectStatus", nullable = false,columnDefinition = "varchar(50) default 'start'")` annotaions but getting errors

my entity class is

```
package com.ults.hrms.model;

// default package
// Generated 17 Jan, 2017 12:04:43 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnDefault;


@Entity
@Table(name = "t_projectmaster", catalog = "db_hrms")
public class Projectmaster implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer projectId;
    private String projectUserIdtemp;
    private String projectUserIdper;
    private String projectName;
    private String clentName;
    private String projectDesc;
    private Double projectValue;
    private String projectTax;
    private Date targetDate;
    private Integer accountmanager;
    private Integer projectManager;
    private byte[] pofile;
    private byte[] agreementFile;
    /*@Column(name = "ProjectStatus",columnDefinition = "varchar(50) default 'ToStart'")*/
    private String projectStatus;
    private Boolean actvieStatus;
    private Date creationDate;
    private Date modifiedDate;
    private Integer userId;
    private String remarks;

    public Projectmaster() {
    }

    public Projectmaster(String projectStatus) {
        this.projectStatus = projectStatus;
    }

    public Projectmaster(String projectUserIdtemp, String projectUserIdper,
            String projectName, String clentName, String projectDesc,
            Double projectValue, String projectTax, Date targetDate,
            Integer accountmanager, Integer projectManager, byte[] pofile,
            byte[] agreementFile, String projectStatus, Boolean actvieStatus,
            Date creationDate, Date modifiedDate, Integer userId, String remarks) {
        this.projectUserIdtemp = projectUserIdtemp;
        this.projectUserIdper = projectUserIdper;
        this.projectName = projectName;
        this.clentName = clentName;
        this.projectDesc = projectDesc;
        this.projectValue = projectValue;
        this.projectTax = projectTax;
        this.targetDate = targetDate;
        this.accountmanager = accountmanager;
        this.projectManager = projectManager;
        this.pofile = pofile;
        this.agreementFile = agreementFile;
        this.projectStatus = projectStatus;
        this.actvieStatus = actvieStatus;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ProjectID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getProjectId() {
        return this.projectId;
    }

    public void setProjectId(Integer projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    @Column(name = "ProjectUserIDTemp", length = 50)
    public String getProjectUserIdtemp() {
        return this.projectUserIdtemp;
    }

    public void setProjectUserIdtemp(String projectUserIdtemp) {
        this.projectUserIdtemp = projectUserIdtemp;
    }

    @Column(name = "ProjectUserIDPer", length = 50)
    public String getProjectUserIdper() {
        return this.projectUserIdper;
    }

    public void setProjectUserIdper(String projectUserIdper) {
        this.projectUserIdper = projectUserIdper;
    }

    @Column(name = "ProjectName")
    public String getProjectName() {
        return this.projectName;
    }

    public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
        this.projectName = projectName;
    }

    @Column(name = "ClentName", length = 100)
    public String getClentName() {
        return this.clentName;
    }

    public void setClentName(String clentName) {
        this.clentName = clentName;
    }

    @Column(name = "ProjectDesc", length = 65535)
    public String getProjectDesc() {
        return this.projectDesc;
    }

    public void setProjectDesc(String projectDesc) {
        this.projectDesc = projectDesc;
    }

    @Column(name = "ProjectValue", precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public Double getProjectValue() {
        return this.projectValue;
    }

    public void setProjectValue(Double projectValue) {
        this.projectValue = projectValue;
    }

    @Column(name = "ProjectTax", length = 50)
    public String getProjectTax() {
        return this.projectTax;
    }

    public void setProjectTax(String projectTax) {
        this.projectTax = projectTax;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "TargetDate", length = 10)
    public Date getTargetDate() {
        return this.targetDate;
    }

    public void setTargetDate(Date targetDate) {
        this.targetDate = targetDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "Accountmanager")
    public Integer getAccountmanager() {
        return this.accountmanager;
    }

    public void setAccountmanager(Integer accountmanager) {
        this.accountmanager = accountmanager;
    }

    @Column(name = "ProjectManager")
    public Integer getProjectManager() {
        return this.projectManager;
    }

    public void setProjectManager(Integer projectManager) {
        this.projectManager = projectManager;
    }

    @Column(name = "POFile")
    public byte[] getPofile() {
        return this.pofile;
    }

    public void setPofile(byte[] pofile) {
        this.pofile = pofile;
    }

    @Column(name = "AgreementFile")
    public byte[] getAgreementFile() {
        return this.agreementFile;
    }

    public void setAgreementFile(byte[] agreementFile) {
        this.agreementFile = agreementFile;
    }

    @Column(name = "ProjectStatus", nullable = false,columnDefinition = "varchar(50) default 'start'")
    public String getProjectStatus() {
        return this.projectStatus;
    }

    public void setProjectStatus(String projectStatus) {
        this.projectStatus = projectStatus;
    }

    @Column(name = "ActvieStatus")
    public Boolean getActvieStatus() {
        return this.actvieStatus;
    }

    public void setActvieStatus(Boolean actvieStatus) {
        this.actvieStatus = actvieStatus;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "CreationDate",columnDefinition = "DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE", length = 19)
    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return this.creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "ModifiedDate", length = 19)
    public Date getModifiedDate() {
        return this.modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(Date modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "UserID")
    public Integer getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "Remarks", length = 65535)
    public String getRemarks() {
        return this.remarks;
    }

    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of exception you got? Can you show exception message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for you,

Initialise the attribute while creating object only.

```
private String projectStatus = "start";
```

Comment: its works for me...could you tell me why i get error use this code @Column(name = "ProjectStatus",columnDefinition = "varchar(50) default 'ToStart'")

Comment: can you try this @Column(length = 32, columnDefinition = "varchar(32) default 'ToStart'").

Comment: @luee this is due to you are giving column name in capitals and JPA expecting name in camel case format.
i.e. projectStatus

Comment: its not working @Column(length = 32, columnDefinition = "varchar(32) default 'ToStart'")

Comment: ProjectStatus attribute is already created in your table so you need to clean db then try once.